# Bootstrap typeahead not working with dynamic array retrieved from a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to create a autocomplete box that gets stock symbols and names from finance.yahoo.com according to the user query typed in typeahead text box.

I created a **quote_form.php** page in which there is a text box on which i applied jquery keyup function to get the characters when typed by the user and then based on that characters i made a get request inside my typeahead function on my php page called **symbols.php** which inturn calls this link below:

**http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=$search&region=US&lang=en-US&callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks**

In the above link $search contains the characters received by get request and then in response i received JSON data with some junk i cleared the junk and then made it a legitimate JSON data and from that JSON data i created a string that looks like javascript array with the field i needed from the JSON. So, when my **quote_form.php** receives that data it does not shows it in typeahead. I surely receive data as i have seen in chrome's inspect element's Network tab. The code for both the pages is as below, i have created a seperate html header so i will not include the same as it is not necessary:

I have included the necessary javaScript files and CSS files:

**jquery version used: 1.8.2**

**Bootstrap version used: v2.2.1**

**quote_form.php**

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var key;
    $("input[name='symbol']").keyup(function() {
        console.log("Key pressed");
        window.key = $(this).val();
    });

    $("input[name='symbol']").typeahead({
        source: function(query, process) {
        return $.get('symbols.php', {s: window.key}, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            return process(data);
            });
        }
    });

});

</script>

<form action="quote.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input id = "sy" autofocus autocomplete ="off" name="symbol" placeholder="Symbol" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Get Quote</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**symbols.php**

```
<?php
    $search = $_GET['s'];

    $url = "http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=$search&region=US&lang=en-US&callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks";

    $raw_data =  @file_get_contents($url);

    $json = substr($raw_data, strpos($raw_data,'Result"') - 1);
    $json = rtrim($json, '})');
    $json = "{" . $json . "}";

    $result = json_decode($json, true);

    $jsarr = "[";
    foreach($result as $symbols)
    {
    foreach($symbols as $symbol)
    {
        $jsarr .= "'".$symbol['name'] . " " . $symbol['symbol'] . "', ";
    }
    }

    $jsarr .= "]";

    echo $jsarr;
?>
```

I also tried the above code without converting to JavaScript array i.e i also tried with JSON only but that didn't work either. Seen many examples on internet also but still i am missing something don't know what. If any body can figure out what i am doing wrong that would be a great relief for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't need the keyup function, that's what the query parameter in the source function is for, also what is the result of `console.log(data)` in your $.get callback?

Comment: output of console.log(data) is: ['symbolname1 stocksymbol1', 'symbolname2 stocksymbol2','symbolnameN stocksymbolN',]. though the answer given by you works like a charm. I was not knowing how to implement that callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yahoo API is actually returning a JSONP callback, you can avoid the parsing by making a `jsonp` request directly from jquery, you just need to build the YAHOO object that's specified in the callback:

```
var $typeaheadInput = $("input[name='symbol']");
$typeaheadInput.typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=' + query + '&region=US&lang=en-US',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonpCallback: 'YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks'
        });
    }
});

//Build YAHOO object with callback function
YAHOO = {
    util: {
        ScriptNodeDataSource: {
            callbacks: function (data) {
                var sourceArray = $.map(data.ResultSet.Result, function (elem) {
                    return elem.name + ' - ' + elem.symbol;
                });
                $typeaheadInput.data('typeahead').process(sourceArray);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Here's a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/rX4TE/)**

**Note:** I removed the `autofocus` attribute from the input because it was causing issues with the typeahead dropdown

Comment: Hi @koala_dev your solution worked flawlessly from long time but suddenly it has stopped working. Now whenever I run above code I am getting a HTTP 400 error. Even the working fiddle link you shared on your answer is not working now, earlier it used to work. It would be great if you could please help.
Also I would like to say that your solution is still working on my local server but not on the server where I hosted my website and also it is not working on jsfiddle either.